# Javascript - looping through data with each click

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm fairly new to Javascript I have been playing with some data fetching for the past few days. I created this very simple program (if you can even call it that), where if you click a button, it will generate a div with a random user (using jsonplaceholder API). My issue is, that whenever the button is clicked, it gives me all 10 users at once. I'd like it to give me one user with each click instead. As I said, I am fairly new to JS so I'm not sure how to aproach this (I guess some sort of a loop would be involved?). Any sort of advice, tips or anything would be welcomed ! Thank you !

Here is my code (Using Bootstrap 4 for styling and Axios for data fetching):

```js
    const mainButton = document.getElementById('mainButton');
    const targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
    
    mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(function(response) {
          let ourRequest = response;
          renderData(ourRequest.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    
      function renderData(data) {
        var stringHTML = "";
    
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          stringHTML += `
              <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            User ID: #${data[i].id}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">${data[i].name}</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Email - <em>${data[i].email}</em></p>
                            <p class="card-text">Phone - <em>${data[i].phone}</em></p>
                            <p class="card-text">Address - <em>${data[i].address.street}, ${data[i].address.city}, ${data[i].address.zipcode}</em></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
              `;
        }
    
        targetDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", stringHTML);
      }
    });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>JSON Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center my-5">
            <h1 class="display-4">Random JSON Users</h1>
            <p>This is a random user generator, click the below button to get a 
    random person!</p>
            <button id="mainButton" class="btn btn-primary">Get User!</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Users -->
        <div id="targetDiv" class="row">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: some sort of loop is already involved, when you do a `for` on `data` array. To add only one element, you could remove the loop and add the html code for a given value of `i`. Next step would be to choose on what criteria to define this value. A good exercise would be to try to verify at one point if the user has already been added to the DOM

Comment: I removed the for loop and hardcoded the array index into my stringHTML, so now on each click I get the first user of the array rendered into the DOM (not all of them at once). My issue now is, I really don't know how if I click again I get the second user from the array, then the third and so on....

Comment: you could give an id to your html card element so you can find it afterwards (something with a prefix to be sure it's unique, like `<div class="card" id="userCard_${data[i].id}">`). You could then loop on data and test if html element exists with this id before you add it. There are other solutions, such as remebering last one added, in javascript, or creating a kind of API server-side to request only one user at a time. depends on how you want it to be optimized

Comment: Well as I mentioned above....I'm pretty new to this so, the simpliest solution will do :) Thank you for your quick responses. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: a simple optimization would be to get the array only once, though, and keep it in a variable. It would mean separate the 2 operations (get the users / display them). It is always good to think about the way your page loads and how you treat the question to know if data is loaded or not before display, these kind of structure organization

Comment: Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right that your GET method is asking for **users**, so response contains more that one user. This response you send to `renderData` method and there you generate your div for each user from response. I supouse to change your GET method to get only one user or send only one user to `renderData` method like `ourRequest.data[0]` from your current solution.